# SQL Server 2008: is there a way to create a trigger like this?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What I would like to do is to create a trigger for my table where anytime someone makes and update, I log the username/nym, GetDate(), and the name of the table being updated into another table called something like "Updates"

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a trigger for each table - you cannot have a "ueber-trigger" that handles all tables at once.

Inside that trigger, you can have something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAuditing
ON dbo.YourTableName
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Updates(TableName, UserName, Date)
     SELECT "YourTableName", SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE()
END
```

Again: do this for each table of interest, and you should be fine!